# SSL peer not authenticated

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

I've still yet to solve this. This is a work in progress. I'm actively learning, and im posting my progress as i go. I'm sorry this thing is so obnoxiously long, its mostly errorlogs.

Edit:4/4/14: I was tinkering around a bit with chrome and i noticed a cool option "preserve logs" while in "inspect element". This was cool because it allowed me to see a hidden post to the server. The post didnt help me much though, there must be something else going on behind the scenes im not seeing. the post i did looked something like this:

```
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "https://ssb.sunydutchess.edu/pls/prod/bwskfshd.P_CrseSchdDetl");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("term_in:","201401"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse postResponse=client.execute(post,context);
```

and im posting AFTER i log into my school. I still get an error, but its a DIFFERENT error, which is usually good. this is my error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server selected improper ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHello(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:533)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:401)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at login.schedule(login.java:188)
at login.<init>(login.java:49)
at launch.main(launch.java:4)
```

I'm trying to simply log into my schools website, then navigate to a page that requires the user to be logged in(view schedule). I have a feeling that after i log in, i'm not STAYING logged in.

Heres some code highlighting my problem:

```
 HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
 CookieStore cookies=new BasicCookieStore();//update here
 HttpContext context=new BasicHttpContext();//update here
 context.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookies);//update here
 HttpPost post =new HttpPost("https://schoolwebsite.edu/login");
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "password"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", 
                    "username"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse postResponse=client.execute(post,context);//update here
 //the failed login page displays Error:failed login   
 //and im using Jsoup to scrape data off the site                
 Document doc= Jsoup.parse(postResponse.getEntity().getContent()
                ,null,"https://is-lump4-web.sunydutchess.edu/cp/home/next");

        if(doc.toString().contains("Error: Failed Login")
                ||
                doc.toString().contains("Error: System Error"))
        {
            System.out.println(doc.toString());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("i logged in");
        }
```

This works fine, and i log in. I'm confident i login because i buffer the welcome page,
no problems.

Now, when i try to go to a page that require me to be logged in using this code:

```
            /**these are not the correct paths, 
            im just highlighting what im trying to do**/      
    HttpGet request=new HttpGet("https://schoolwebsite.edu/mySchedule");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request,context);//CRASHES HERE
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException ie) {}
```

i get the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

Also, i'm seeing some cookies are not being accepted by my HttpClient and i have no idea why

```
 Mar 19, 2014 4:57:13 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies       processCookies
 WARNING: Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: WebCTTicket][value: ][domain:    webct.cookie.domain][path: /][expiry: Wed Dec 31 19:00:10 EST 1969]". Illegal domain    attribute "webct.cookie.domain". Domain of origin: "is-lump4-web.sunydutchess.edu"
 Mar 19, 2014 4:57:13 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies    processCookies
 WARNING: Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: WebCTTicket][value: ][domain:  webct.cookie.domain][path: /][expiry: Wed Dec 31 19:00:10 EST 1969]". Illegal domain  attribute "webct.cookie.domain". Domain of origin: "is-lump4-web.sunydutchess.edu"
 Mar 19, 2014 4:57:13 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies   processCookies
WARNING: Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: WebCTTicket][value: ][domain:  webct.cookie.domain][path: /][expiry: Wed Dec 31 19:00:10 EST 1969]". Illegal domain    attribute "webct.cookie.domain". Domain of origin: "is-lump4-web.sunydutchess.edu"
 Mar 19, 2014 4:57:14 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies   processCookies
 WARNING: Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: WebCTTicket][value: ][domain:   webct.cookie.domain][path: /][expiry: Wed Dec 31 19:00:10 EST 1969]". Illegal domain       attribute "webct.cookie.domain". Domain of origin: "is-lump4-web.sunydutchess.edu"
```

after the edit, some of the cookies are no longer being rejected(i removed the ones that are not giving me an error)
I'm guessing this might be the source of the problem? I've read up and seen some code on
SSL, but i feel as though that might be the wrong approach. After all, I'm seeing the welcome page with no problems. A point in the right direction would be amazing. 

EDIT: I tried some things with cookiestore and local context, but im still getting the same error. the edit is included in the code.

EDIT2: I'm using httpClient V4.3... and im trying to connect to a schools website. the certificate is coming from entrust certification authority L1C.. its name is ssb.sunydutchess.edu

EDIT3: Ok, so after poking around i stumbled across a debugging technique

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
```

after using that i found some interesting stuff:

```
i logged in
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
main, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1395348688 bytes = { 70, 23, 87, 62, 213, 199, 80, 63, 213, 254, 145, 204, 158, 60, 108, 63, 35, 111, 106, 222, 17, 230, 72, 198, 146, 202, 19, 87 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 74
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1811840364 bytes = { 227, 236, 190, 135, 95, 39, 232, 229, 21, 230, 238, 131, 216, 249, 98, 40, 196, 101, 185, 198, 154, 50, 113, 92, 184, 247, 227, 165 }
Session ID:  {105, 218, 73, 202, 12, 94, 203, 197, 94, 188, 149, 223, 217, 67, 129, 194, 3, 236, 211, 3, 0, 96, 47, 48, 188, 75, 80, 47, 106, 226, 232, 178}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
***
Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = illegal_parameter
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server selected improper ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
main, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server selected improper ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

can anyone give me some leeway on what all this means? why is it closing? and whats with the  unavailable/unsupported ciphersuites ??

Comment: Shouldn't there be colons in your urls?

Comment: yeah, sorry. I'm not actually trying to connect to http//somesite.com/login, im just illustrating im trying to connect to a http site with ssl. ill update the mistake. thanks

Comment: Is this a site you own? Is it a production site, or a development copy? Is it possible that it is using self-signed certificates?

Comment: Also, what version of HttpClient are you using?

Comment: I'm using httpClient V4.3... and im trying to connect to a schools website.. ill put this information into the question.

Comment: The SSL session isn't relevant to the HTTP session. They aren't co-extensive.

Comment: right, but im connecting through https.. im not really sure how you answer helps my problem. what are you trying to say?

Comment: you're saying my problem isnt with the http session, just the SSL? what do you propose i go about doing?

Comment: @soricella It wasn't an answer, it was a comment, and it was made about ten thousand edits ago.